# Dynamically populate a page

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile

I am new to mobile applications, and since i have a strong html, js, css background i decided to try cordova using angularjs. Anyway, i have hit a road block and i don't know the best way to handle this.

I have this block that is setup to repeat; x.large and x.thumb are pulled from a json file via Angular.

```
    <div class="gallery" ng-controller="imagelistController">
        <div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="x in urls">
            <a href="{{x.large}}"><img src="{{x.thumb}}"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to setup a single page using a query string href links to a page such as image.html?id=1.  In image.html i want it do display image 1. If you change the id to 2, it would show image 2.

```
    <div ng-controller="imagelistController">
          <img src="{{x.large}}">
    </div>
    <ul class="social-share">
        <li><button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, '{{x.large.url}}', null)">image only</button></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js"></script>
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could go about this, but you should consider Angular's router (or ui-router might work better for your specific use case, you can have multiple named views.)  See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route and (or ui-router at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.)  If you would rather roll your own (really those two routers are really great and user friendly), look into using window.local.hash and hashchange events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will read up on ui-routers. If i have questions i will respond to this thread.